# Memcached not working in web browser,but use php command working

Tags: php, memcached

I have  testMemcached.php code below.

```
<?php
include_once "common.php";
include_once "api.php";
class TestMemcached extends API{
    function impl(){
         $m = $this->getMem();
         $stats = $m->getStats();
         var_dump($stats);

        $m->add("Key","test");
        echo "Value:".$m->get("Key");
    }
}
$api = new TestMemcached();
$api->go();
```

I run  testMemcached.php in the web browser. I  get `bool(false) Value:`.

I run `php -f testMemcached.php` command then get the output below.

```
array(1) {
  ["localhost:11211"]=>
  array(24) {
    ["pid"]=>
    int(10218)
     ....(skip)
    ["version"]=>
    string(6) "1.4.15"
  }
}
Value:test
```

I don't know what the difference is and 
how to fix memcached not working in the web browser.

My environment:CentOS 7. LNMP.

**2018/05/23 Update :**
I use `telnet 127.0.0.1 11211` to test memcached function
I found the `add` and `set` is not working.

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
set test testValue
ERROR
add test testValue 
ERROR
get test
END
```

This is my memcached setup from phpinfo below.
[image: This is my memcached setup from phpinfo]

I use `getResultCode()` code below to find some error
This is my test result output.

```
MemcachedFunction ResultCode ErrorDescription
stats 3 MEMCACHED_CONNECTION_FAILURE
set 3 MEMCACHED_CONNECTION_FAILURE
add 47 MEMCACHED_SERVER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED
get 47 MEMCACHED_SERVER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED
fetchAll 16 MEMCACHED_NOTFOUND
```

My Test Code is here. Output is in comments.

```
<?php
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$m = new Memcached();
$m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);
$m->addServer("localhost","11211");
$stats = $m->getStats();
echo "stats ".$m->getResultCode()."<br>"; // stats 3
var_dump($stats); // bool(false)
echo "<br>";
$m->set("Key","test");
echo "set ".$m->getResultCode()."<br>"; // set 3
$m->add("Key","test");
echo "add ".$m->getResultCode()."<br>"; // add 47
echo "Value:".$m->get("Key")."<br>"; // Value:
echo "get ".$m->getResultCode()."<br>"; // get 47
var_dump($m->fetchAll()); // bool(false) 
echo "<br>";
echo "fetchAll ".$m->getResultCode()."<br>"; // fetchAll 16
var_dump($m->getAllKeys()); // bool(false)
```

Comment: These are the relevant runtime configuration options: http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.configuration.php. Compare your php.ini file between the CLI options and your webserver's options.

Comment: @Mike I only find "extension=extension=/usr/local/php-memcached/modules/memcached.so", and "memcache.serializer = igbinary",no other setting about memcached

Comment: Is that the same as your webserver's php.ini?

Comment: except memcached.sess_lock_wait is not set, other setting is the same .
I already add "memcached.sess_lock_wait=150000" into php.ini then restart php-fpm,but have no effect.

Comment: Well looking at your phpinfo file it looks like memcached is enabled for the web server. Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the code above you are extending `API`, but haven't included that code.

Comment: @Mike I already add my test code, please help me to find other solution.

Comment: Based on the comments from the [Memcached::getResultCode() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getresultcode.php), result code 3 means "MEMCACHED_CONNECTION_FAILURE".

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `$m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);`?

Comment: I comment it then test but still not work before. I'll try again.

Comment: Any one can help?

Comment: I don't have any more ideas. I have never used memcached before, so I can't really be of too much help. To get more attention to this question, try adding a bounty to it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced alittle similiar issue once.
In my case using ip address instead of 'localhost' worked.

```
$cache_server_host = '12*.45*.***.***';// Your server's ip address here.
$cache_server_port = 11211;

$cache_obj = NULL;
$is_cache_available = FALSE;

try {
  if (class_exists('Memcache')) {
    $cache_obj = new Memcache;
    $is_cache_available = $cache_obj->connect($cache_server_host, $cache_server_port);
  };
}
catch (Exception $e) {}

if (!empty($is_cache_available)) {
  // Ok to use the cache;
  // i.e.- $cache_obj->set($key, $val, ...);
}
```

Comment: I try to use public ip, still can't fix the problem.

Comment: Try with 127.0.0.1 instead? 敬錞潘

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this issue is related with IP vs hostname. I faced the same issue with official Memcached docker . it was not working with 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1 but when tested with DNS name or container IP it worked.

```
<?php

/**
 * @license MIT License
 * @copyright maartendekeizer
 */

$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer('memcached', 11211);

$name = 'testkey';
$ttl = 10;
$data = sha1(time());

$memcached->set($name, $data, $ttl);
echo date('His') . ': key "' . $name . '" set to "' . $data . '" with ttl ' . $ttl . PHP_EOL;

for ($i = 0; $i < ($ttl + 5); $i ++) {
  $res = $memcached->get($name);
  echo date('His') . ': key "' . $name . '" data is "' . $res . '" and that is ' . ($res == $data ? 'a match' : 'not a match') . PHP_EOL;
  sleep(1);
}
```